# Low rep user has to suggest an edit to own answer?

Tags: support, users, suggested-edits

So I was perusing through the suggested edit queue and came across this suggestion:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/37540

I saw the suggestion as a change from a broken link, to a personal blog which is not the sort of changes we should be allowing AFAIK so I rejected it.  However immediately after rejecting, I just noticed that it was the original answerer suggesting an edit *to his own answer*.  That's odd.  Regrettably, I wish I could take back that rejection and instead approve it.

What just happened here?  Why does he have to go through the process suggesting an edit?  It's his answer, why can't he immediately edit it?  Did something fall out of sync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at the user profiles. They have the same name, but different ID's.  This user probably has created a second account by mistake.

Comment: HA! I was puzzling over this apparent self-edit that inexplicably turned up in the Suggested Edits queue: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2860200. In fact, it turns out to be two accounts with the same name, same rep, and obviously the same person. Apparently he thought he needed to do that in order to answer his own question...with an answer that's really a comment, that I just flagged for deletion - so it was a doubly wasted effort. :).

Answer (score 3):

It's not the same account. Now that the edit is approved one has 3 rep, the other 1.

Comment: It's definitely clearer now, especially with the approval going through.  Though initially, that was not the case.

Comment: Yes, i was surpised as well when i saw the edit (before it was approved)